# Android Studio java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Launch

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror, android-studio, launch, build.gradle

I added the module dependency in build.gradle and apparently Android Studio doesnt complain, no compilation errors. but when I hit "Run" to launch the app I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

I'm using Android Studio's Gradle.

I tried:
gradle clean + gradle assemble and got successful build, but still failed on launch.

my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile group:'com.deebl', name:'deebl-client-core', version:'0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
07-07 14:03:23.833      790-790/com.deebl                  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.deebl.client.core.be.Movie
    at com.deebl.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: my bad, just added it. do you have any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: One of three reasons: com.deebl.client.core.be.Movie is either a misspelling, got eliminated or renamed during packaging (proguard, etc), or itself depends on something (extends a library class, etc) which was not present at install time, and so was itself removed from the package by the installer.  In the latter case it is possible you would see something in the logs during the install (if you do a complete uninstall first) though I can't promise that would be the case.  You may also find it interesting to use a reverse engineering tool to unpackage your apk and see what is actually there.

Comment: Thanks for the response! the weird thing is that now I have the jar file in the libs folder and still after doing: gradle build. it doesnt get added to the .apk file.

Comment: You may need to fix the build configuration.  But jar files don't end up in apk's, rather classes compiled or extracted from them do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to Android Studio 0.2.0 solved it